# 4-Bit Barrel-Shifter with 4x1 Multiplexers

Tags: microcontroller, multiplexer, shift-register

I have a question regarding an exercise I have to do. I am supposed to build a 4-bit barrel-shifter using 4x1-multiplexers. I have 4 inputs and 4 outputs. The position shift should be n=(2*B)+A. I have built a shifter that could shift the input by three positions, but I don't know how to implement the n=(2*B)+A position shift.

Can someone help?

[image]

Comment: What effect DO you think A and B have on the outputs?

Comment: @Finbarr Well if A is active it means a shift by 2^1, B active a shift by 2^2, A and B active a shift by 2^3

Comment: The specification lacks a *shift direction*. `A and B active a shift by 2^3` No. A circular shift by a multiple of 4 would not change a 4 bit value/register, a linear shift greater than value/register length would either clear or "sign extend" the value. *A and B active* means *shift by* \$2^0 + 2^1\$ more likely than *shift one to the other direction*.

Comment: You're confusing the number of bits it's shifted by with the effective multiplier. A left shift of 1 bit multiplies by 2^1, left shift by two bits by 2^2 and so on.